# What is the difference between Account ID and Contact ID?

Tags: process-builder, tasks

I'm writing a Formula in Process builder to assign an ID to the "Assigned To ID" for a task to be created by the process. When I look at an individual contact, I can choose between a "Contact ID" for that contact or a "Account ID." What is the difference between these two fields?

Comment: What object are you working with? These fields represent relationship to entirely different objects, `Contact` and `Account`. Not sure if you're looking for anything further than that?

Comment: Are you referring to a Task's Assigned To Id? If so, Assigned To is a User so you are looking at the User's Account Id and Contact Id fields. Neither can be assigned as the Assigned To since it is expecting a User Id

Comment: Bobforce, yes, I am referring to Task's Assigned To Id and so your answer solves my problem. I have switched over the forumula to use CreatedBy.Id and it appears to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from Adrian Larson and Bobforce above (and further research) here's how I answer my question:

The Account ID is the ID number for the Account Object. The Account object is where Salesforce stores information about a business or organization that is part of the sales process.

For example, they are "ABC Genius Tech Consulting" in this scenario from "Salesforce Trailhead:

> "You’re preparing to meet with Alan and Leung from ABC Genius Tech Consulting. You’ve done your research in reviewing their company’s past history with Cloud Kicks. Now you need to make sure you understand how the people, their company, and your team fit together. By understanding the relationships between contacts, accounts, and your internal team of sales reps, you’re able to close deals more effectively and efficiently." From Trailhead module ["Understanding Account and Contact Relationships"](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/admin_intro_accounts_contacts/admin_intro_accounts_contacts_relationships)

The Contact ID is the identification number for the Contact object. In the above example, Alan and Leung are the two contacts, both of whom are part of the ABC Genius Tech Consulting account object.

When filling in the "Assigned To ID" field when creating a Task via the Process Builder, the ID needed is the User ID, which is the ID for the user object, the object tied to the Salesforce user themselves. You can read more about that object in Salesforce trailhead here: [What is a user?](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lex_implementation_user_setup_mgmt/lex_implementation_user_setup_mgmt_adding_users)